# Viewport meta tag changes dynamically jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

We have a PhoneGap based app that has been built on jQuery Mobile. Currently we are trying to explicitly set the viewport using the viewport meta tag.

For example we set the following in the html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.6"/>
```

And on our login screen and dashboard this works, however in a different page the viewport is overridden to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

When we had a look at the jQuery Mobile code it showed that depending on if zoom was enabled or not this updated viewport set, the following is part of the JQuery mobile library code which is responsible for updating the viewport.

```
var meta = $( "meta[name=viewport]" ),
        initialContent = meta.attr( "content" ),
        disabledZoom = initialContent + ",maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no",
        enabledZoom = initialContent + ",maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes",
        disabledInitially = /(user-scalable[\s]*=[\s]*no)|(maximum-scale[\s]*=[\s]*1)[$,\s]/.test( initialContent );
```

However this is not set for the first two pages. When we checked if we had set `disablePageZoom` in the code we couldn't find anything or anything else that would trigger this change.

How could we keep the viewport the same without it being changed by jQuery Mobile or any workarounds.

Note that the viewport change occurs on `$.mobile.changePage` when the page changes and we are using jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 in this app.

Comment: Could you add working code snippet?

Comment: updated the question with more information though that is pretty much it when considering the set of code snippets to add.

Comment: It's too difficult to make any conclusion from this information.